# Why does bitwsie AND operation 00000100000001000001000100 & 11111100000000000000000000 === 0?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

`00000100000001000001000100`

`11111100000000000000000000`

Each binary number's length is `26`, and I expected the result to be `100000000000000000000`. I'm confused why the result is 0.

```js
const a = 00000100000001000001000100;
const b = 11111100000000000000000000;
console.log(a & b)
```

Is it because JS treats `11111100000000000000000000` as a signed number?

Comment: `11111100000000000000000000` is not binary, it's a very large decimal number.

Comment: @ CertainPerformance How can I let JS know it's a binary number? Actually, this number is from a string. The length of it is `26` is because I use each bit to represent a letter. `1` means the letter appears at least once in a string. Then, I used `&` to see if there is no common letters in both strings.

Comment: See the linked canonical.

Comment: Binary number starts with `0b` just like hex numbers starts with `0x`. If your number is a string (that is if it is `"1001"` instead of `1001`) then you can use `parseInt()` to parse it: `parseInt(your_binary_string, 2)` <-- note that you tell `parseInt` to treat the string as a base 2 number ("binary" is another name for base 2 numbers)